# Double sort with reverse

Tags: python

It is easy to implement a regular double sort:

```
pairs = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3), (2, 4), (3, 1)]

sorted(pairs,key=lambda x: (x[0],x[1]))
# out: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1)]
```

I am interested how to do it with the second elements in the reverse order. This can be easily implemented by grouping the pairs by the first item at first and then adding the the sorted second items together. I have implemented this both using `itertools.groupby` and `defaultdict`. Still, it remains far more complex, than the regular double sort, so i wonder, if there is a neat trick to do it in a more concise way.

```
double_sort(pairs)
# out: [(1, 3), (1, 2), (2, 4), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

*PS! I know how to do it with `numpy.argsort` and would mostly like to see a standard lib approach.*

Comment: Your lambda is doing nothing at all. `sorted(pairs)` already gives the same result as your first sort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work for numbers and similar data types

```
sorted(pairs, key=lambda x: (x[0], -x[1]))
```

This will work for all comparable types only in Python 2 :(

```
sorted(pairs, lambda x, y: cmp(x[0], y[0]) or cmp(y[1], x[1]))
```

Comment: +1, after seeing something like this, it feels pretty stupid:)